# Magento 2 load dynamic values to select field in XML

Tags: magento2, module, database, forms

i am new in Magento development. I am trying to create a new module for adding dynamic fields for product edit page.

Now I was able to add the fields in admin's product edit page. now I want to show a select box filed there with dynamic values which should be loaded from my table.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
   <fieldset name="magenest">
   <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
       <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
           <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Material Price Calculation Fields</item>
           <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
           <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data.magenest</item>
           <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
       </item>
   </argument>
   <field name="status">
       <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
           <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Status</item>
               <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">status</item>
               <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
               <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">field</item>
               <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
               <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
               <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
                       <item name="value" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                       <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Inactive</item>
                   </item>
                   <item name="1" xsi:type="array">
                       <item name="value" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                       <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Active</item>
                   </item>
               </item>
           </item>
       </argument>
   </field>

</fieldset>
</form>
```

You can see currently I am hardcoded values here. now I have to display values from my table materials.

can you please help me how can i do this?

Comment: You can create select box for product using `Admin->Stores->Attributes->Product`. By programmatically please visit -> https://webkul.com/blog/create-drop-down-product-attribute-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 2):

Make your field look like this:

```
    <field name="status" formElement="select">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">10</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <dataType>text</dataType>
            <label translate="true">Label</label>
            <dataScope>status</dataScope>
        </settings>
        <formElements>
            <select>
                <settings>
                    <options class="[Vendor]\[Module]\Model\Status"/>
                </settings>
            </select>
        </formElements>
    </field>
```

Then create the class `[Vendor]\[Module]\Model\Status`.

```
namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Model;

class Status implements \Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface
{
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $options = [];
        $options[] = [
            'label' => __('Inactive'),
            'value' => 0,
        ];
        $options[] = [
            'label' => __('Active'),
            'value' => 1,
        ];
        return $options;
    }
}
```

Now you can change the method `toOptionArray` to return the values you need.

Comment: That is cool, but how can i load data from my table here?

Comment: Use the repository or collection for the entity associated to that table.

Comment: can you give me an example? I don't understand this correctly. I am not familiar with these